# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar el error en C# Visual Studio 2017 para poder acceder al diseñador?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy realizando una aplicación en C#, usando Visual Studio 2017. Necesito añadir un checkbox, algo que no es complicado. El problema es que en la mayor parte de los formularios de la aplicación, no puedo acceder al diseño, porque me aparece el siguiente problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no he entendido mal, hay uno o varios objetos que no han sido instanciados. He estado revisando código, y creo que todos los controles han sido instanciados. Además, al compilar, no me aparece ningún error al respecto.

Por otra parte, tampoco puedo iniciar la aplicación. Se queda anclada en esta línea de código, en Program.cs:

```
Application.Run(frmPrincipal);
```

Y no me produce ningún fallo de compilación. Para detectar los errores, ¿hay alguna forma de detectarlos? He estado mirando línea a línea, y parece que está bien (y evidentemente, no lo está). Gracias por adelantado.

Por cierto, en la pila de llamadas me aparece esto (para mí, bastante difícil de descifrar):

Instancias de este error (1)

```
1.   Ocultar pila de llamadas 
 
en System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create(IDictionary resourceList, String baseName, String generatedCodeNamespace, String resourcesNamespace, CodeDomProvider codeProvider, Boolean internalClass, String[]& unmatchable)
en System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create(IDictionary resourceList, String baseName, String generatedCodeNamespace, CodeDomProvider codeProvider, Boolean internalClass, String[]& unmatchable)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.BuildType()
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.GetObjectType()
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalType.get_ObjectType()
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.get_Children()
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjectsForItem(ProjectItem item, GlobalObjectCollection oldObjects, GlobalObjectCollection newObjects, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjectsForItem(ProjectItem item, GlobalObjectCollection oldObjects, GlobalObjectCollection newObjects, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjects(Project project)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.GetGlobalObjectsCore(Project project, Type baseType)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectProvider.GetGlobalObjects(Project project, Type baseType)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectService.GetGlobalObjects(Type baseType)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetTypeFromGlobalObjects(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name)
en System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.GetType(String typeName)
en System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
en System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola, seguramente borraste algo que se crea en el diseñor de la vista. Hace click en mostrar pilla de llamadas, busca la linea que te marca en rojo, ese evento que borraste, quitalo de ahi.

Comment: Puede presionar F7 para ver el codigo?

Comment: Hola Duston. Si puedo, pero no marca ningún error ni fallo. Gracias.

Comment: Intenta mirar en el archivo `.Designer.cs` del formulario que te falla, a ver si ahi te marca algun error